# how to use the "sizeof" operator with "virtual" operator

Tags: c++

i have the following code in my small program

```
          class myc {
             int dummy;
                public:
             virtual int si(){return sizeof(*this);}
               };


             int main() {
                 myc a;

          cout<<a.si()<<endl;

          cin.get();

              return 0;
              }
```

the output is 8 , but as i expect it should be 4 
Can someone tell why 
when i change the si() method to
                          `virtual int si(){return sizeof(*this);}`
                to 
                        `int si(){return sizeof(*this);}`

i get the correct output , i.e 4

Comment: `virtual` isn't an operator.

Comment: With the virtual, you get a vtable in the class.

Comment: What makes you think that 4 is "correct"?

Comment: A virtual class requires, in the instance header, a pointer to the virtual function table.